# Creating Documents Sitefinity backend non admin user

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, sitefinity

I'm running into a problem with the telerik sitefinity api. I'm trying to create pdf certifications in the backend and publish them to the documents library. Here is my code for how I create and publish the certifications.

```
   byte[] byteArray = reportViewer.LocalReport.Render("PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out fileNameExtension, out streamids, out warnings);

                var documentLibraryList = SitefinityHelper.GetDocumentLibraries();

                string certificationLibraryTitle = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CertificationLibrary"].ToString().ToUpper();

                DocumentLibrary certLibrary = null;

                //Make sure the parent library exists before doing anything else.
                foreach (DocumentLibrary library in documentLibraryList)
                {
                    if (library.Title.ToUpper() == certificationLibraryTitle.ToUpper())
                    {
                        certLibrary = library;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                //If not null, good to create the pdf cert, but need to check for previous ones.
                if (certLibrary != null)
                {
                    try
                    {


                        string pdfCertificationTitle = currentUser.UserName + "_"+ "Certification_" + moduleViewModel.ExamID.ToString();

                        UserCertifications previousCertifcationRecord = certBo.GetUserCertificationByTitle(pdfCertificationTitle);

                        if (previousCertifcationRecord == null)
                        {
                            //No previous record exists, create the new record. 

                            MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);

                            Guid documentID = Guid.NewGuid();

                            string format = ".pdf";

                            LibrariesManager librariesManager = LibrariesManager.GetManager();

                            Document pdfDocument = librariesManager.CreateDocument(documentID);

                            DocumentLibrary parentLibrary = librariesManager.GetDocumentLibraries().Where(d => d.Id == certLibrary.Id).SingleOrDefault();

                            pdfDocument.Parent = parentLibrary;

                            pdfDocument.Title = pdfCertificationTitle;
                            pdfDocument.DateCreated = DateTime.UtcNow;
                            pdfDocument.PublicationDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                            pdfDocument.LastModified = DateTime.UtcNow;
                            pdfDocument.UrlName = Regex.Replace(pdfCertificationTitle.ToLower(), @"[^\w\-\!\$\'\(\)\=\@\d_]+", "-");

                            librariesManager.RecompileAndValidateUrls(pdfDocument);
                            librariesManager.Upload(pdfDocument, memStream, format);

                            librariesManager.SaveChanges();

                            var bag = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                            bag.Add("ContentType", typeof(Document).FullName);

                            WorkflowManager.MessageWorkflow(documentID, typeof(Document), null, "Publish", false, bag);

                            string fullUrl = SitefinityHelper.GetDocumentUrl(pdfCertificationTitle);

                            //Save the certification to the DB.
                            certBo.InsertNewUserCertification(pdfCertificationTitle, fullUrl, currentUser.UserID);
                        }
                    }

                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        ExceptionManager.LogException(this, ex);
                    }
                }
```

The exception message that I'm running into is:

**Telerik.Sitefinity.Libraries.Model.DocumentLibrary, Telerik.Sitefinity.Model was not granted ManageDocument in Document for principals with IDs**

However, this exception, only occurs when I try to create and publish the pdf document when I'm logged in as a non-admin / non-backend user. When I'm logged in as a backend user this code executes just fine. I believe there must be a way to set a permission in order to allow non-backend users the proper authority to create documents but I just dont know how and googling didn't reveal much. If anyone could please help I would really appreciate it.

This is using Sitefinity version 6.2

Answer (score 3):

Sitefinity has built in security infrastructure, which allows you to assign who can do different stuff with built-in and custom data types. The exception you are getting means that the current principal with which you are trying to create the document does not have proper rights for this action. What you can do is either check the permissions for document libraries and grant this type of user the necessary privileges, or elevate the security context and skip the security checks. To bypass security checks surround your code with the following (the part where you use libraries manager):

```
        LibrariesManager librariesManager = LibrariesManager.GetManager();

        using(new ElevatedModeRegion(librariesManager))
        {

            Document pdfDocument = librariesManager.CreateDocument(documentID);

            DocumentLibrary parentLibrary = librariesManager.GetDocumentLibraries().Where(d => d.Id == certLibrary.Id).SingleOrDefault();

            pdfDocument.Parent = parentLibrary;

            pdfDocument.Title = pdfCertificationTitle;
            pdfDocument.DateCreated = DateTime.UtcNow;
            pdfDocument.PublicationDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
            pdfDocument.LastModified = DateTime.UtcNow;
            pdfDocument.UrlName = Regex.Replace(pdfCertificationTitle.ToLower(), @"[^\w\-\!\$\'\(\)\=\@\d_]+", "-");

            librariesManager.RecompileAndValidateUrls(pdfDocument);
            librariesManager.Upload(pdfDocument, memStream, format);

            librariesManager.SaveChanges();

            var bag = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            bag.Add("ContentType", typeof(Document).FullName);

                            bool suppressSecurityChecks = WorkflowManager.GetManager().Provider.SuppressSecurityChecks;
            try
            {
                WorkflowManager.GetManager().Provider.SuppressSecurityChecks = true;
                WorkflowManager.MessageWorkflow(documentID, typeof(Document), null, "Publish", false, bag);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            finally 
            {
                WorkflowManager.GetManager().Provider.SuppressSecurityChecks = suppressSecurityChecks;
            }  
      }
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm having a problem with the second using block. Specifically "Telerik.Sitefinity.Workflow.WorkFlowManager.MessageWorkflow cannot be accessed with an instance reference, qualify it with a type name instead.

Comment: I tried with the above edit. The exception listed above is still thrown.